# Tuple out of index

Tags: tuples, indexoutofboundsexception

IndexError: tuple index out of range

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure why, because my code looks like

```
interpolated_mean = np.array([np.ones(X.shape[1])*self.means[digit] for digit in range(10)])
```

where `self.means` returns

```
[0.2950995723007362, 0.35157590125195076, 0.37957208825304445, 0.3191758946180043, 0.35155769941304243, 0.3984539137236574, 0.3008216529579752, 0.3630624989356188, 0.4623879642875728, 0.33528044078766084]
```

Comment: Did you check what `X.shape` returns?

Comment: Try ```interpolated_mean = np.array([np.ones(X.shape[0])*self.means[digit] for digit in range(len(self.means)])``` Also what is X?

Comment: X is a n-by-d matrix (with n data points and d features). My desired result is an array of 10 vectors of length d that have self.means[row#] as their entries. So I want self.means to be copied d times and stacked.

Comment: Wait I think it was indeed an issue with X.shape - which returned (). Thank you guys!